# How to replace a specific element in a List

Tags: c#

The idea is I receive input that is then splited in a list, the 1st element of which is `"Windows"` in the current case. Then the program receives another input - `changeOS`. Then the 1st element of the list should be replaced by the value in the string `changeOS`, which is `Linux`
in the current case, but i don't know how to do it, so i hope someone helps.

```
string input = Console.ReadLine(); //Windows 16GB 3600Hz 1TB 
List<string> specs = input.Split(" ").ToList();//Windows 16GB 3600Hz 1TB ...after // Linux 16GB 3600Hz 1TB
string changeOS = Console.ReadLine(); //Linux
Console.WriteLine(specs[0]); //Linux
```

Comment: `specs[0] = changeOS;`?

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine I can't believe it was that easy. I was trying ```specs.Replace()``` or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the suggestion of the first comment, this should do what you want:

```
string input = Console.ReadLine(); //Windows 16GB 3600Hz 1TB 
List<string> specs = input.Split(" ").ToList();//Windows 16GB 3600Hz 1TB ...after // Linux 16GB 3600Hz 1TB
string changeOS = Console.ReadLine(); //Linux
specs[0] = changeOS;
Console.WriteLine(specs[0]); //Linux
```